# Dealing with BTRFS ref/backpointer mismatches, backref missing

Tags: btrfs

A btrfs filesystem reported some errors during `btrfs receive` operation due to some missing extends. From the log:

```
BTRFS error (device dm-1): unable to find ref byte nr 190303420416 \
      parent 0 root 594  owner 1 offset 0
BTRFS: error (device dm-1) in __btrfs_free_extent:6944: errno=-2 No such entry
BTRFS info (device dm-1): forced readonly
BTRFS: error (device dm-1) in btrfs_run_delayed_refs:2956: errno=-2 No such entry
```

A `btrfs scrub` (after a umount + mount) failed with similar errors.

A `btrfs check` reports issues for 3 extends - each extend issue is reported like this:

```
checking extents
ref mismatch on [190303420416 16384] extent item 0, found 1
Backref 190303420416 parent 594 root 594 not found in extent tree
backpointer mismatch on [190303420416 16384]
owner ref check failed [190303420416 16384]
```

My question is: how can I translate those numbers to something useful? For example to check if some files/directories are impacted?

And how to deal with such errors?

A `btrfs check --repair` seems to work without complaining severely:

```
  ref mismatch on [190303420416 16384] extent item 0, found 1
* repair deleting extent record: key 190303420416 169 1
* adding new tree backref on start 190303420416 len 16384 parent 0 root 594
  Backref 190303420416 parent 594 root 594 not found in extent tree
  backpointer mismatch on [190303420416 16384]
  owner ref check failed [190303420416 16384]
```

(the `*` marks are mine)

Does this mean that the repair was successful without loosing any data?

Comment: Related: [thread on the btrfs-linux mailinglist](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-btrfs/msg67177.html) where several users describe the same sequence of btrfs errors. Spoiler: the thread is inconclusive on this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A successful `btrfs check --repair` command doesn't necessarily yield a consistent btrfs filesystem.

In one case I observed that a `btrfs scrub` after  `btrfs check` triggered several `WARN_ON()` tests in `fs/btrfs/extent-tree.c`. And receiving snapshot yielded an IO failure (which forced a readonly remount).

Thus, since the runtimes of a `btrfs check`, followed by a `btrfs check --repair` and a `btrfs scrub` can be quite significant - and those actions have uncertain outcomes: a practical alternative is to just re-create the btrfs filesystem and restore a backup.

**2021-12-14 Followup:** FWIW, these errors were caused by a faulty/low-quality USB hub (vendor string: 'Genesys Logic, Inc.'). After directly attaching the USB disk drives those errors never appeared again. Before that, such errors appeared every few months or so when daily sending snapshots to an external USB drive. I even had another Genesys USB Hub around (differently labeled though) which I tried, but it yielded a similar error pattern.